# How to assign a variable with the first two characters of a passed argument in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, pipe, pipeline

So I want to assign a variable in bash that takes piped code from head.

```
first2chars=$[[ echo $1 | head -c 2 ]]
```

but when I want to use this I get an error of:

```
[ echo -n2 | head -c 2 ]: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[ echo -n2 | head -c 2 ]")
```

Figured it out:

```
first2chars=$(echo $1 | head -c 2)
```

the above code works

Comment: What do you think `$[[ ... ]]` means?

Comment: do inside, like () in C

Comment: So, you're just making up syntax and assuming it does what you want? Languages don't work that way.